MariaDB: Can't update large table after ALTER
I have a database that I have imported from mysql dump, it's around 1GB and 4.3 million rows. (It is the compact dump from libgen from here https://data.library.bz/dbdumps/). After I import this table called updated, I drop several columns and add a two new ones. (I put the schema and changes at the bottom.) After this, I am not able to update the table anymore. Even the most basic changes e.g. UPDATE updated SET title = 'something' WHERE id = 1 fail with ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'libgen.updated_edited' doesn't exist. Inserts still succeed. If I turn on full logging I see the UPDATE followed by an INSERT into the _edited table, but the INSERT is using the original table schema. I'm not sure what this signifies...
240802 16:19:12     12 Query    UPDATE updated SET title = 'something' WHERE id = 1
                    12 Query    INSERT INTO `updated_edited`
SET
        `Title` = OLD.`Title`,
        `VolumeInfo` = OLD.`VolumeInfo`,
        `Series` = OLD.`Series`,
<snip>
        `Identifier` = OLD.`Identifier`,
        `ISSN` = OLD.`ISSN`,
        `ASIN` = OLD.`ASIN`,
        `UDC` = OLD.`UDC`,
        `LBC` = OLD.`LBC`,
<etc>...

This issue doesn't happen with the same schema + changes with a small dataset (a couple of rows). Recreating the db produces exactly the same issue. I have tried using InnoDB instead of MyISAM, but there is no change. In the logs I don't see any errors, or warnings.
This issue is really hard to search for because the error message is... not helpful and obviously just returns a lot of bogus results where someone spelled the table name wrong.  Can someone even just explain what is this _edited table? It might give me some options of things to look at.

I am using mariadb 10.7.3 in the official docker image on macbook M3 with Sonoma.
This is the original table schema as its imported:
CREATE TABLE `updated` (
  `ID` int(15) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Title` varchar(2000) DEFAULT '',
  `VolumeInfo` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `Series` varchar(300) DEFAULT '',
  `Periodical` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `Author` varchar(1000) DEFAULT '',
  `Year` varchar(14) DEFAULT '',
  `Edition` varchar(60) DEFAULT '',
  `Publisher` varchar(400) DEFAULT '',
  `City` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `Pages` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `PagesInFile` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Language` varchar(150) DEFAULT '',
  `Topic` varchar(500) DEFAULT '',
  `Library` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `Issue` varchar(100) DEFAULT '',
  `Identifier` varchar(300) DEFAULT '',
  `ISSN` varchar(9) DEFAULT '',
  `ASIN` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `UDC` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `LBC` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `DDC` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `LCC` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `Doi` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `Googlebookid` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `OpenLibraryID` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `Commentary` varchar(10000) DEFAULT '',
  `DPI` int(6) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `Color` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Cleaned` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Orientation` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Paginated` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Scanned` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Bookmarked` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Searchable` varchar(1) DEFAULT '',
  `Filesize` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `Extension` varchar(50) DEFAULT '',
  `MD5` char(32) DEFAULT '',
  `Generic` char(32) DEFAULT '',
  `Visible` char(3) DEFAULT '',
  `Locator` varchar(733) DEFAULT '',
  `Local` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0,
  `TimeAdded` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '2000-01-01 05:00:00',
  `TimeLastModified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
  `Coverurl` varchar(200) DEFAULT '',
  `Tags` varchar(500) DEFAULT '',
  `IdentifierWODash` varchar(300) DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `MD5` (`MD5`),
  KEY `Generic` (`Generic`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisibleTimeAdded` (`Visible`,`TimeAdded`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `TimeAdded` (`TimeAdded`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Topic` (`Topic`(3)) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisibleID` (`Visible`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `VisibleTimeLastModified` (`Visible`,`TimeLastModified`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `TimeLastModifiedID` (`TimeLastModified`,`ID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `DOI_INDEX` (`Doi`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Identifier` (`Identifier`),
  KEY `Language` (`Language`),
  KEY `Extension` (`Extension`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title` (`Title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Author` (`Author`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Language_FTS` (`Language`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Publisher` (`Publisher`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Series` (`Series`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Year` (`Year`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Title1` (`Title`,`Author`,`Series`,`Publisher`,`Year`,`Periodical`,`VolumeInfo`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Tags` (`Tags`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `Identifierfulltext` (`IdentifierWODash`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4357935 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_general_ci;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

These are the alters I do after its imported:
ALTER TABLE updated
DROP COLUMN Identifier,
DROP COLUMN issn,
DROP COLUMN asin,
DROP COLUMN udc,
DROP COLUMN lbc,
DROP COLUMN DDC,
DROP COLUMN LCC,
DROP COLUMN Doi,
DROP COLUMN Googlebookid,
DROP COLUMN OpenLibraryID,
DROP COLUMN Topic,
DROP COLUMN Local,
DROP COLUMN Tags,
DROP COLUMN Timelastmodified,
DROP COLUMN TimeAdded,
DROP COLUMN Coverurl,
DROP COLUMN Locator,
DROP COLUMN Visible,
DROP COLUMN Generic,
DROP COLUMN Searchable,
DROP COLUMN Bookmarked,
DROP COLUMN Scanned,
DROP COLUMN Paginated,
DROP COLUMN Orientation,
DROP COLUMN Cleaned,
DROP COLUMN Color,
DROP COLUMN DPI,
DROP COLUMN Commentary,
DROP COLUMN Library,
DROP COLUMN City,
ADD COLUMN ext
enum('pdf','epub','djvu','doc','mobi','zip','rar','azw3','fb2','rtf','chm','docx','txt','cbr','lit','html','gz','7z','cbz'),
ADD COLUMN lang
enum('aa','ab','af','ak','am','ar','an','as','av','ae','ay','az','ba','bm','be','bn','bi','bo','bs','br','bg','ca','cs','ch',
  'ce','cu','cv','kw','co','cr','cy','da','de','dv','dz','el','en','eo','et','eu','ee','fo','fa','fj','fi','fr','fy','ff',
  'gd','ga','gl','gv','gn','gu','ht','ha','sh','he','hz','hi','ho','hr','hu','hy','ig','io','ii','iu','ie','ia','id','ik',
  'is','it','jv','ja','kl','kn','ks','ka','kr','kk','km','ki','rw','ky','kv','kg','ko','kj','ku','lo','la','lv','li','ln',
  'lt','lb','lu','lg','mh','ml','mr','mk','mg','mt','mn','mi','ms','my','na','nv','nr','nd','ng','ne','nl','nn','nb','no',
  'ny','oc','oj','or','om','os','pa','pi','pl','pt','ps','qu','rm','ro','rn','ru','sg','sa','si','sk','sl','se','sm','sn',
  'sd','so','st','es','sq','sc','sr','ss','su','sw','sv','ty','ta','tt','te','tg','tl','th','ti','to','tn','ts','tk','tr',
  'tw','ug','uk','ur','uz','ve','vi','vo','wa','wo','xh','yi','yo','za','zh','zu');


Version details:
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "%version%";
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                     | Value                                    |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
| in_predicate_conversion_threshold | 1000                                     |
| innodb_version                    | 10.7.3                                   |
| protocol_version                  | 10                                       |
| slave_type_conversions            |                                          |
| system_versioning_alter_history   | ERROR                                    |
| system_versioning_asof            | DEFAULT                                  |
| tls_version                       | TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3                  |
| version                           | 10.7.3-MariaDB-1:10.7.3+maria~focal      |
| version_comment                   | mariadb.org binary distribution          |
| version_compile_machine           | aarch64                                  |
| version_compile_os                | debian-linux-gnu                         |
| version_malloc_library            | system                                   |
| version_source_revision           | 65f602310c4ea086488bfaa50f36952162541a8c |
| version_ssl_library               | OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020              |
| wsrep_patch_version               | wsrep_26.22                              |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+
15 rows in set (0.00 sec)


it is impossible that the update command would produce that result also where comes the table  * INSERT INTO updated_edited*  you at least talk about updated that comes from somewhere but you never talked about upodated_edited, where did you create it

It doesn't exist, I never created it. There's only one table in the db. The only place it appears is in the INSERT statement in the logs.

your post i confusing, your code above shows such an insert command, that must come from some where

Instead of DROPping lots of columns, create a new table and copy into it via INSERT..SELECT... the the columns you want.
